# PearOS - Is it actually Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, pear

I just downloaded PearOS 7 for both its look and the fact that it was linux... Until I thought about it. PearOS is a distro that was made by a french developer. Does it use the kernel that say... Ubuntu would use?

Comment: what does uname -a say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it looks just like Ubuntu with a different theme and likely it uses the same kernel.

From [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=pear), *Pear Linux is a French Ubuntu-based desktop Linux distribution.*